# How to fill jsp session with jquery value?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

**This is my code :**

```
<form name="f">
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="OK" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"/>
<input type="text" id="browser_version" name="browser_version" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="browser_type" name="browser_type"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {

        var browser_version = $("#browser_version").val();
        var browser_type = $("#browser_type").val();

         alert(" browser_version   :    " + browser_version);
         alert(" browser_type   :    " + browser_type);       
    });
</script>
</form>
```

**Input text Filling with jQuery and this code is :**

```
<% String browser_version = request.getparameter(browser_version); %>
```

**is null.**
**How to fill jsp session with jquery value ?**

**If possible with an example.**

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not clear. Which value do you want to make available in session? Or do you want to put some value in request!! By the way "request.getparameter(browser_version)" means you are retrieving some parameter with this name, and this parameter should be passed by server while putting this request.

Comment: ldiot : Sorry for the unclear question that I asked.
Yes, I have both.   ( make available in session Or some value in request)
THX

Comment: Unfortunately
I am Searching the internet